# How to remove the floating action button

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I have the layout as:

[image]

As you can see, there is this floating icon that I no longer wish to use.
The XML is simply:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/repeatPasswordEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:hint="repeat password"
    android:editable="true"
    android:password="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/sign_up"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Username"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView6" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Password"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:editable="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:editable="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usernameEditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/usernameEditText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/usernameEditText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/usernameEditText"
    android:password="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="First Name"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/repeatPasswordEditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Last Name"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstNameEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/firstNameEditText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/repeatPasswordEditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/repeatPasswordEditText"
    android:editable="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/repeatPasswordEditText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/repeatPasswordEditText" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lastNameEditText"
    android:editable="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstNameEditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/firstNameEditText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/firstNameEditText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/firstNameEditText" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lastNameEditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lastNameEditText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Email"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lastNameEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sign_up"
    android:id="@+id/signUpUserButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="62dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Phone #"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumEditText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/emailEditText" />
```

How can this icon be removed permanently?

Comment: can you post the full xml?

Comment: @cwfei I have posted the full XML

Comment: check in layouts, there will be another layout file with `CoordinatorLayout` .In that layout file remove `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` view.

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati I see, it was within the activity_sign_up.XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a sample code it is embedded by default in application.

To remove this floating Icon; please follow below steps :

```
      1. Remove complete "FloatingActionButton" tag and their elements from 
         "activity_main (as default implementation)".

      2. To make neat source code, need to remove "FloatingActionButton" 
         method from "MainActivity (as default implementation)".
```

Hope it would help!

Cheers!

Comment: For number 2. **To** make neat source code, need to remove "FloatingActionButton" the method **from** "HomeActivity (as default implementation)".

Answer (score 0):

First time I was also wondering about to remove this button.
But it is so simple.

Step 1: find **app_bar_main.xml** and ***remove*** this code:

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Step 2: Go to your activity (for example *MainActivity.java*) and ***remove*** this bunch of code from the **onCreate()** method of the activity:

```
  FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```