# Remove FloatingActionButton and ActionBar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am new to Android development however lately when I choose a 'Blank' activity I am getting some 'Included Layout' that I can not seem to get rid of. As shown below it adds a blue top border and a email picture at the bottom right.

[image]

I have made a few small apps before and have never had these before. Now I make a blank activity and I get these. I know I can click 'hide' however that only hides them in the layout in Android and not in the application. The application still has these annoying things.

Comment: post your activity & xml file .

Comment: post your code first.. including manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

choose `empty activity` instead of `blank activity` when you create new project .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The pink button is called `FloatingActionButton`. Just remove the three lines of code in your `onCreate()` creating it and it will be gone.

The blue top border is called `ActionBar`. Change the extended class from `AppCompatActivity` to just `Activity` and that will be gone too.

Comment: I do not have anything in my on create

Comment: I removed those previously and both are still here :/

Comment: share your xml and oncreate method in the question

Comment: Choosing an Empty Activity seemed to be the easier way, However, I made a new one for blank activity and took what you said and it worked so perhaps there was a bag in the other blank activities creation. Wish I could mark you both correct

Comment: yes if you are just starting with a new activity it is an easier way

Answer (score 0):

That comes from with blank Activity which it has two layouts(there are two xml layout in the `res/layout`) which the first one has a `FloatingActionButton` as default!

And if you need to delete the content, you should be able to remove `include` from main layout and then see what is going on on the refering layout called `content_main`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though question is answered satisfactorily to the asker. I still feel there is room to have one more answer as below.

Yes, If one no need any-more of these default implementations; selecting "Empty Activity" over "Blank Activity" would give some edge of not messing up.

But, there is no harm to select "Blank Activity" design. It just supplies some default embedded codes(corresponds to pink floating action button as well as menu action bar) which appears the root of issue to asker. And it can be removed if not required any-more.

```
1. To remove floating button please follow the answer given at following link.
        <a> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780393/how-to-remove-the-floating-action-button/34852617#34852617 </a>


2. To remove "menu action bar" please follow these steps as below :
              -> Remove complete "AppBarLayout" tag and their elements from "activity_main (as default implementation)".

              ->  To make neat source code, need to remove two override methods [i.e. onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)]  from "MainActivity (as default implementation)".
```

Hope it would provide some easiness in activity selection.

Cheers!